# Horizon not Synchronizing ("import session failed: failed to load header: sql: no rows in result set" pid=8077)

Tags: horizon

<< Background >>

Private network of 4 nodes on 4 VMs, hosted on same server.

Core and Horizon built on 1 VM, and then 3 copies were made from this VM. NODE_SEED (core) & corresponding IP (Horizon & friendbot) were changed correspondingly.

All Horizons have the flag "--ingest=true", and other flags identical except for friendbot IP.

> 

As I submitted a transaction to **node1**, the reponse looks like:

```
{ _links:
   { transaction:
      { href: 'http://192.168.7.81:8000/transactions/e148053e6eb998ab3b8c8eb2e316054a58a602223f1e7978ce2cc9c08b5230ec' } },
  hash: 'e148053e6eb998ab3b8c8eb2e316054a58a602223f1e7978ce2cc9c08b5230ec',
  ledger: 123501,
  envelope_xdr: 'AAAAAOtyZp2+5xgJ5ugpgr2IJn72iZzB4dkFLP34zSKLAvn4AAAAZAAAAUQAACGLAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAQAAAACOFIVTgnqFCLqO/8a9EsD/3PRh/+50+TZRJAlefXEc3gAAAAEAAAAA0UEBLBX9GjP1iM5G48jbNuW6K1Vdd05ExCvR4fRVNnUAAAACQXNzMXRvMAAAAAAAAAAAAI4UhVOCeoUIuo7/xr0SwP/c9GH/7nT5NlEkCV59cRzeAAAAAACJVEAAAAAAAAAAAosC+fgAAABAc8d0ngvx2Nux+oTSe1qrndaxG10jRgeP+M1N22csIGQW1W6jXA+NKxw1A/VB27uiQls85ih3tS4ndNW/78QRDn1xHN4AAABAtIXOwrHTYdzQuqyHdjiNZ9ayvvA969xZ7cZdxRiypGcepb7YCcMBom40mZZMqi0uDpqCMV8+f0yJr4FJkL2sBQ==',
  result_xdr: 'AAAAAAAAAGQAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAA=',
  result_meta_xdr: 'AAAAAAAAAAEAAAACAAAAAwAB4jkAAAABAAAAANFBASwV/Roz9YjORuPI2zbluitVXXdORMQr0eH0VTZ1AAAAAkFzczF0bzAAAAAAAAAAAACOFIVTgnqFCLqO/8a9EsD/3PRh/+50+TZRJAlefXEc3gAAEXjIWKPAf/////////8AAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAHibQAAAAEAAAAA0UEBLBX9GjP1iM5G48jbNuW6K1Vdd05ExCvR4fRVNnUAAAACQXNzMXRvMAAAAAAAAAAAAI4UhVOCeoUIuo7/xr0SwP/c9GH/7nT5NlEkCV59cRzeAAAReMjh+AB//////////wAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAA==' }
```

> 

Then I curl the href on Horizon of **node1** (Res404):

```
curl http://192.168.7.81:8000/transactions/e148053e6eb998ab3b8c8eb2e316054a58a602223f1e7978ce2cc9c08b5230ec
```

---

```
{
  "type": "https://stellar.org/horizon-errors/not_found",
  "title": "Resource Missing",
  "status": 404,
  "detail": "The resource at the url requested was not found.  This is usually occurs for one of two reasons:  The url requested is not valid, or no data in our database could be found with the parameters provided."
}
```

> 

While curl **node2** gives the correct info (Res200):

```
curl http://192.168.7.82:8000/transactions/e148053e6eb998ab3b8c8eb2e316054a58a602223f1e7978ce2cc9c08b5230ec
```

---

```
{
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://192.168.7.82:8000/transactions/e148053e6eb998ab3b8c8eb2e316054a58a602223f1e7978ce2cc9c08b5230ec"
    },
    "account": {
      "href": "http://192.168.7.82:8000/accounts/GDVXEZU5X3TRQCPG5AUYFPMIEZ7PNCM4YHQ5SBJM7X4M2IULAL47R45Q"
    },
    "ledger": {
      "href": "http://192.168.7.82:8000/ledgers/123501"
    },
    "operations": {
      "href": "http://192.168.7.82:8000/transactions/e148053e6eb998ab3b8c8eb2e316054a58a602223f1e7978ce2cc9c08b5230ec/operations{?cursor,limit,order}",
      "templated": true
    },
    "effects": {
      "href": "http://192.168.7.82:8000/transactions/e148053e6eb998ab3b8c8eb2e316054a58a602223f1e7978ce2cc9c08b5230ec/effects{?cursor,limit,order}",
      "templated": true
    },
    "precedes": {
      "href": "http://192.168.7.82:8000/transactions?order=asc\u0026cursor=530432756027392"
    },
    "succeeds": {
      "href": "http://192.168.7.82:8000/transactions?order=desc\u0026cursor=530432756027392"
    }
  },
  "id": "e148053e6eb998ab3b8c8eb2e316054a58a602223f1e7978ce2cc9c08b5230ec",
  "paging_token": "530432756027392",
  "hash": "e148053e6eb998ab3b8c8eb2e316054a58a602223f1e7978ce2cc9c08b5230ec",
  "ledger": 123501,
  "created_at": "2018-03-13T06:17:32Z",
  "source_account": "GDVXEZU5X3TRQCPG5AUYFPMIEZ7PNCM4YHQ5SBJM7X4M2IULAL47R45Q",
  "source_account_sequence": "1391569412491",
  "fee_paid": 100,
  "operation_count": 1,
  "envelope_xdr": "AAAAAOtyZp2+5xgJ5ugpgr2IJn72iZzB4dkFLP34zSKLAvn4AAAAZAAAAUQAACGLAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAQAAAACOFIVTgnqFCLqO/8a9EsD/3PRh/+50+TZRJAlefXEc3gAAAAEAAAAA0UEBLBX9GjP1iM5G48jbNuW6K1Vdd05ExCvR4fRVNnUAAAACQXNzMXRvMAAAAAAAAAAAAI4UhVOCeoUIuo7/xr0SwP/c9GH/7nT5NlEkCV59cRzeAAAAAACJVEAAAAAAAAAAAosC+fgAAABAc8d0ngvx2Nux+oTSe1qrndaxG10jRgeP+M1N22csIGQW1W6jXA+NKxw1A/VB27uiQls85ih3tS4ndNW/78QRDn1xHN4AAABAtIXOwrHTYdzQuqyHdjiNZ9ayvvA969xZ7cZdxRiypGcepb7YCcMBom40mZZMqi0uDpqCMV8+f0yJr4FJkL2sBQ==",
  "result_xdr": "AAAAAAAAAGQAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAA=",
  "result_meta_xdr": "AAAAAAAAAAEAAAACAAAAAwAB4jkAAAABAAAAANFBASwV/Roz9YjORuPI2zbluitVXXdORMQr0eH0VTZ1AAAAAkFzczF0bzAAAAAAAAAAAACOFIVTgnqFCLqO/8a9EsD/3PRh/+50+TZRJAlefXEc3gAAEXjIWKPAf/////////8AAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAHibQAAAAEAAAAA0UEBLBX9GjP1iM5G48jbNuW6K1Vdd05ExCvR4fRVNnUAAAACQXNzMXRvMAAAAAAAAAAAAI4UhVOCeoUIuo7/xr0SwP/c9GH/7nT5NlEkCV59cRzeAAAReMjh+AB//////////wAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAA==",
  "fee_meta_xdr": "AAAAAgAAAAMAAeI5AAAAAAAAAADrcmadvucYCeboKYK9iCZ+9omcweHZBSz9+M0iiwL5+AAAABdIac4YAAABRAAAIYoAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAeJtAAAAAAAAAADrcmadvucYCeboKYK9iCZ+9omcweHZBSz9+M0iiwL5+AAAABdIac20AAABRAAAIYsAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==",
  "memo_type": "none",
  "signatures": [
    "c8d0ngvx2Nux+oTSe1qrndaxG10jRgeP+M1N22csIGQW1W6jXA+NKxw1A/VB27uiQls85ih3tS4ndNW/78QRDg==",
    "tIXOwrHTYdzQuqyHdjiNZ9ayvvA969xZ7cZdxRiypGcepb7YCcMBom40mZZMqi0uDpqCMV8+f0yJr4FJkL2sBQ=="
  ]
}
```

Horizon DB on all 4 nodes checked, and only node2 has the new record; node1,3,4 has no such record.

Looking into the Horizon logs of node1,3,4, this message repeats:

```
"import session failed: failed to load header: sql: no rows in result set" pid=8077
```

Any suggestions for the cause/solution?

===================

p.s. Querying the involved account gives the same asset amounts on all 4 nodes. So this seems not to be an issue with core.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT** There'a a new article explaining potential recovery steps: https://www.stellar.org/developers/software/known-issues.html

Looks like you are falling into this [issue](https://github.com/stellar/go/issues/335). stellar-core `ledgerheader` table can have gaps. For example it has ledgers: 45000-46000 and then the next ledger is ledger: 50000. This can happen when you have `CATCHUP_RECENT` parameter set and stellar-core was not working for some time.

Currently the only way to fix this is to clear Horizon database.