# Stellar Horizon not synchronizing

Tags: stellar-core, horizon, validators

Background:

- Using `satoshipay/stellar-horizon:0.11.1` for Horizon

Stellar Core seems to be running. Based on logs, we get the latest sequence number and ledger:

```
2018-04-18T10:31:32.695 GDYMW [Ledger INFO] Got consensus: [seq=8508865, prev=fc51bd, tx_count=7, sv: [ txH: c3108f, ct: 1524047493, upgrades: [ ] ]]
2018-04-18T10:31:37.620 GDYMW [Herder INFO] Quorum information for 8508864 : {"agree":3,"disagree":0,"fail_at":2,"hash":"273af2","missing":0,"phase":"EXTERNALIZE"}
2018-04-18T10:31:37.630 GDYMW [Ledger INFO] Got consensus: [seq=8508866, prev=1e8788, tx_count=7, sv: [ txH: 6deefc, ct: 1524047497, upgrades: [ ] ]]
2018-04-18T10:31:37.630 GDYMW [Ledger INFO] Got consensus: [seq=8508866, prev=1e8788, tx_count=7, sv: [ txH: 6deefc, ct: 1524047497, upgrades: [ ] ]]
```

Setup Horizon to read from Stellar Cores Database. Horizon ENV Variables:

```
INGEST = true
CATCHUP_RECENT = 1440
HISTORY_RETENTION_COUNT = 1000
STELLAR_CORE_DATABASE_URL = <redacted>
STELLAR_CORE_URL = <redacted>
DATABASE_URL = <redacted>
```

Stellar Core and port is reachable from the Horizon machine. Horizon runs, but I don't see `core_latest_ledger` being updated:

```
"horizon_version": "",
"core_version": "v9.1.0",
"history_latest_ledger": 0,
"history_elder_ledger": 0,
"core_latest_ledger": 1,
"core_elder_ledger": 0,
"network_passphrase": "Test SDF Network ; September 2015",
"protocol_version": 9
```

Checked the Horizon logs:

```
time="2018-04-18T10:38:28Z" level=error msg="import session failed: failed to load header: sql: no rows in result set" pid=1
```

Checked here, and it looks like someone else encountered the problem: [Horizon not Synchronizing ("import session failed: failed to load header: sql: no rows in result set" pid=8077)](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/688/horizon-not-synchronizing-import-session-failed-failed-to-load-header-sql-n)

I cleared the Horizon Database and restarted Horizon. Horizon Database was reinitialized and horizon is running again, but I still encountered the same error:

```
level=error msg="import session failed: failed to load header: sql: no rows in result set" pid=1
```

I ran through the steps here: https://www.stellar.org/developers/horizon/reference/admin.html#correcting-gaps-in-historical-data

I didn't encounter any errors, but after restarting Horizon I encountered the same error:

```
level=error msg="import session failed: failed to load header: sql: no rows in result set" pid=1
```

My last resort would be to clear the `stellar-core` database and make sure it has no gaps. Any advice on the next steps?

UPDATE:

I updated Horizon to 0.12.3. Horizon runs and I no longer encounter the `import session` error, however I encountered another error:

```
level=warning msg="ingest: waiting for stellar-core sync"
```

I tried with an empty horizon database and I still get this error.

Comment: Can you try upgrading to the latest Horizon. I think that a lot of ingestion issues were fixed in v0.12.x.

Comment: Thanks Bartek! I'll try doing this and update the question

Comment: Hi Bartek! I upgraded to the latest Horizon, but I encountered another error `level=warning msg="ingest: waiting for stellar-core sync"`

Comment: You need to wait until stellar-core synced with the network, check "state" value at /info endpoint. Should be:
> "state" : "Synced!"

Comment: Thanks Bartek! I think I can consider this as Answered since it's a different problem now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE:

Thanks to Bartek's advice, I no longer encounter this error. I made our own Stellar Horizon Docker image with horizon-v0.12.3.

The `level=warning msg="ingest: waiting for stellar-core sync` error I brought up in our (Bartek and me) exchange of replies in the comment section is different from this question and is not related with this question.